# problem during data update in php ajax

Tags: php, ajax

ajax-

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("lblvoteup").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
//document.getElementById("lblvotedown").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
```

html-

```
<tr>                    
                <td ><img src="images/up.jpeg" style="border:none;" title="Like" 
                onclick="doVote('<?php echo $q_id; ?>','<?php echo $_SESSION['UserId']; ?>','up', '<?php echo $q_up; ?>')"></td>
                <td ><label id="lblvoteup"><?php echo $q_up;?></label></td>
                <td style="border-left:1px solid whitesmoke;"><img src="images/down.jpeg"  style="border:none;" title="Dislike" 
                onclick="doVote('<?php echo $q_id; ?>','<?php echo $_SESSION['UserId']; ?>','down', '<?php echo $q_down; ?>')"></td>
                <td ><label id="lblvotedown"><?php echo $q_down; ?></label></td>
            </tr>
```

problem is I dont want to write another ajax function to update `lblvotedown`.How can i check that which image is clicked in ajax function?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, do the following process

1) let response Text contain the following type of data "down--10" or "up--11" (assuming you are currently getting the updated count of vote down or up)

2) split the data retrieved using the javascript code

`var returns=xmlhttp.responseText.split("--");`

3) use the following in the ajax function

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  var returns=xmlhttp.responseText.split("--");
  if(returns[0]=="up") 
  document.getElementById("lblvoteup").innerHTML=returns[1];
  else
  document.getElementById("lblvotedown").innerHTML=returns[1];
}
}
```

Hope helpful